# Android - How to use SpannableString to place text

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have the next list item which shows two texts, one aligned to the left and one aligned to the right. For now, each text is placed in a different `TextView`:

[image]

I would like to use only one `TextView`. For that, I know I can use `SpannableString`, but I have hours trying to find out the way without success.

Can anyone tell me how I can place both texts in the same `TextView` aligning one to the left and one to the right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want both texts in the same TextView? I don't think you're going to find a simple way to position text like that without using separate views. You could create your own SpannableString, or do it with some hacky blank inline image sizing, but...why bother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i would do:

First you need measure lenght of right side text.

```
            float textsize = messageview.getPaint().getTextSize();
                int lenght = int lenght = textsize * text.length();
```

After that use leadingMarginSpan:

```
public class leadingMarginSpan2 implements LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2{
        private int margin;
        private int lines;

        public leadingMarginSpan2(int lines, int margin){
            this.lines = lines;
            this.margin = margin;
        }
        @Override
        public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas arg0, Paint arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6, CharSequence arg7,
                int arg8, int arg9, boolean arg10, Layout arg11) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
            if(first){
                return margin;
            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getLeadingMarginLineCount() {
            return lines;
        }

    }
```

Set span:

```
spantext.setSpan(new leadingMarginSpan2(1, getWidth() - lenght), 0, text.lenght, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: when you say the length of the right side text, you mean the number or chars from the right side text?

Comment: His code is getting the text size setting, in scaled pixels, and multiplying it by the number of characters. The result is an approximation of the width of the text, but is not exact. It would be more accurate to use getTextBounds() and then get the width of the Rect. Are you sure you don't want to use two TextViews? :)

Comment: @Jorge Gil Yes, i mean number.

Comment: @LorneLaliberte, I wanted try this because I wanted to remove one View from the view tree. I thought this would be easy, but now I know it's completely hard. Thank you guys and I think I'll still using two TextViews.